# Is there a way to use - (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag with a custom UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a class that inherits from UIView

However when trying to use the follow `(UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag` I get the warning: *incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct UIView *', expected 'struct CustomView *'*

Right now I have made a custom method that returns my custom view, the method uses a for loop with view.subviews since the views I am looking for come from the same superview.  I do a conditional check if the tag matches the one I am searching for then I return the view.

I suppose I am just wondering if there is a better practice to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably doing:

```
CustomView * aView = [someView viewWithTag:42];
```

`viewWithTag:` returns a `UIView`, not a `CustomView`.  There are a couple ways around this:

1. Casting.  If you are absolutely sure that you'll only ever get a `CustomView` by doing this, then you can do:

   ```
   CustomView * aView = (CustomView *)[someView viewWithTag:42];
   ```
2. Reflection.  If you're not sure that you're going to get a custom view, then assign it into a `UView` reference and decide later what to do with it:

   ```
   UIView * aView = [someView viewWithTag:42];
   if ([aView isKindOfClass:[CustomView class]]) {
     CustomView * customView = (CustomView *)aView;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that's worked.  I know it will always return the custom class however the additional bit may help at some point